# Should I use the font encoding LY1 with the package libertine?

Tags: libertine, ligatures, font-encodings

I normally use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` without giving it any thought. The package `libertine` seems to provide more ligatures with the `LY1` encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\f}{fb ff fh fi fj fk fl ft}
\begin{document}
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\f

\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\f
\end{document}
```

[image: fb ff fh fi fj fk fl ft]

Are there any drawbacks to using `LY1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what glyph coverage you want. Here's the font table for the T1 encoding

[image]

and here is the table for the LY1 encoding

[image]

You can compare them and decide what suits you best. For English, French or German and some other languages the LY1 coverage seems complete. It's not for the Slavic languages using the Latin alphabet (except perhaps Slovenian).