# Libertine + pdftex: using 'Th' and 'Qu' ligatures with T1 font encoding

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, ligatures, libertine

**Context:** My document uses the `libertine` package and I process it with `pdfTeX`.

`T1` encoding [is better](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677/64454) than `OT1`. A `LY1` encoding [exists](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/ly1) but is less common.

**Problem:** For reasons explained above, I use the `T1` font encoding for my document. However, this font encoding does not provide neither the `Th` nor the `Qu` ligature. I thus looked at similar questions ([Linux Libertine ligatures / T1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95468/64454); [Should I use the font encoding LY1 with the package libertine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107585/64454); and [Linux libertine, the {\l} character, ligatures, and T1 fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229168/64454)) and noted that the font provides different ligatures according to the encoding chosen. Here is the difference (MWE below):

- `OT1` encoding: all ligatures.
  [image]
- `T1` encoding: common ligatures only.
  [image]
- `LY1` encoding: extended ligatures, but not with capital letters.
  [image]

I would like to include at least `Th` and `Qu` ligatures in my document, but also want to benefit from `T1` features (automatic hyphenation, accented characters being recognized as one single glyph), and be sure the text remains copy & past-able as well as search-able through the pdf.

**Question:** How to enable the `Th` and `Qu` ligatures in my document, without loosing `T1` encoding benefits?

*Bonus:* The same question with the less common `fb`, `fh`, `fj`, `fk`, and `ft` ligature.

<sup>*Note:* Processing the document with `LuaTeX` or `XeTeX` is not an option for me (I have no time to shift from `pdfTeX` to another processing systems + [I want to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372910/64454) use `microtype`'s tracking and spacing features), but answers involving them are still welcome.</sup>

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
    Ligatures with \texttt{OT1} encoding:  ff  fi   fl  ffi fb fh fj fk ft Qu Th
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
%   Ligatures with \texttt{T1} encoding:  ff  fi   fl  ffi 
%   
%   No ligature : fb fh fj fk ft Qu Th
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
%   Ligatures with \texttt{LY1} encoding:  ff  fi   fl  ffi fb fh fj fk ft
%   
%   No ligature: Qu Th
\end{document}
```

Comment: T1 has no free slots, see also my comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229168/linux-libertine-the-l-character-ligatures-and-t1-fontenc#comment541204_229186

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Very explanatory, thank you. I should learn further about font encoding. It's surprising though, that glyphs got deleted when switching from OT1 to T1 (i.e. adding 128 more slots)!

Comment: @ebo The 128 additional slots are needed for accented letters supporting most Western Europe languages.

Comment: @egreg This makes sense! I trying to dig into `fonttable` for looking at the various glyphs made available by the T1 encoding.

Comment: Note: As for the sans-serif variant (namely Biolinum), the ligatures `ff`, `ft` and `Qu` (and only them) are enabled in any of the three encodings.

Comment: There are ... er ... ways to do this, but you are better off learning Lua/XeTeX as the transition will be smoother and less time-consuming. Or use a different font.

Comment: There are 5 positions in T1 which can be used for such ligatures. In libertine there are ff, fi, fl, ffi and ffl on this position. Biolinum uses them for ff, ft, tt, QU and a "double exclam". You can check such things with the fonttable package and e.g. `\xfonttable{T1}{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}{m}{n}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but just using LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX) and OpenType fonts you don't have this problem.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
Ligatures with \texttt{TU} encoding:
ff fi fl ffi fb fh fj fk ft Qu Th
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not the answer I hoped, yet the most useful...

Answer (score 4):

Based on karl's answer at [Linux libertine, the {\l} character, ligatures, and T1 fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229168/linux-libertine-the-l-character-ligatures-and-t1-fontenc).  Of course, in this case, the desired ligatures need to be explicitly invoked via macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newcommand{\Th}{\begingroup\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont Th\endgroup}
\newcommand{\Qu}{\begingroup\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont Qu\endgroup}
\begin{document}
I have Th and Qu but I need the ligatures \Th{} and \Qu{} too though.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Changing every instances of `The` into `\Th{}e` does not seem to be, however, a longterm viable solution for my thesis!

Comment: @ebo With a capable text editor, it may not be so bad.

Comment: You are right, but I'm [using butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/) instead (-; The source would look horrible though, and I'd prefer to separate content from layout markup in the sources.

Comment: @ebo You will lose kerning, too. Any font switch breaks kerning.